# behat/mink selenium abstraction layer for python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, behat, mink

So in the PHP world there is an abstraction layer you can use called Mink which runs on top of selenium which gives you a much nicer interface than straight selenium webdriver. An example of what this looks like is below:

```
// set the default session name
$mink->setDefaultSessionName('goutte2');

// visit a page
$mink->getSession()->visit($startUrl);

// call to getSession() without argument will always return a default session if has one (goutte2 here)
$mink->getSession()->getPage()->findLink('Downloads')->click();
echo $mink->getSession()->getPage()->getContent();
```

Is there a similar project to this in the Python world? My google-fu isn't coming up with much. It doesn't necessarily have to be a testing framework, I would like to use it to do some information extraction without having to write straight webdriver code.

Answer (score 1):

[`splinter`](https://splinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) claims to be the one:

> Splinter is an abstraction layer on top of existing browser automation
>   tools such as Selenium, PhantomJS and zope.testbrowser. It has a
>   high-level API that makes it easy to write automated tests of web
>   applications.

Comment: It's pretty good, a little rough around the edges maybe but there seems to be good documentation for using it with lettuce (which would be a more common case).

Comment: @RyanM I've personally tried `splinter` multiple times and I still think bare python selenium bindings are good and clear enough..

Comment: I wish there was a straight port of Mink, it has some really nice methods for doing extremely common tasks (like looking up fields without having to dig into xpaths/ids/classnames/etc).

Comment: @JamesGeraldo sorry, just curious, could you explain why have you unaccepted the answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Robot Framework](http://robotframework.org) for a really high-level interface. It's Python inside but basically works with any language/environment.